# How to use count and for_each in Terraform

Tags: terraform

You can't use count and for_each together :-(
Does anyone have any ideas to help me achieving the below:

Thanks

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "sb" {
  count                  = var.are_there_files_to_upload == true ? 1 : 0
  for_each               = fileset(path.module, "files/*")
  name                   = trim(each.key, "files/")
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.sc.name
  type                   = "Block"
  content_md5            = filemd5(each.key)
  source                 = each.key
}
```

Comment: Without the necessary information about the variable declaration for the `count` meta-argument value (`are_there_files_to_upload`), I would speculate that removing the `count` entirely would fix this issue as it seems extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `count` and `for_each` in the same resource. You need to set your `for_each` to an empty list if `var.are_there_files_to_upload` is `false`:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "sb" {
  for_each               = var.are_there_files_to_upload == true ? fileset(path.module, "files/*") : []
  name                   = trim(each.key, "files/")
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.sc.name
  type                   = "Block"
  content_md5            = filemd5(each.key)
  source                 = each.key
}
```

Although, if the path at `fileset(path.module, "files/*")` is going to be empty if `var.are_there_files_to_upload` is `false`, then you could just do:

```
for_each = fileset(path.module, "files/*")
```

And it will automatically be an empty list when there are no files there.